# Twilio execption in Userscontroller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

I am using twilio to send and receive the sms on the registered mobile number. My problem is my user doesn't get register.Here is my code

**Userscontroller**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @user = User.new
 end

 def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.save
       render text: "Thank you! You will receive an SMS shortly with verification instructions."

    # Instantiate a Twilio client
      client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

    # Create and send an SMS message
    client.account.sms.messages.create(
      from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
       to: @user.phone,
        body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to this message."
    )
    else
       render :new
   end
 end

end
```

Do i need to provide any other code.Let me know if you want.
Can any one please help me with this code.
What i'm doing wrong in controller
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your missing the `=>` and have the `:` on the wrong side.

Try:

```
client.account.messages.create(
  :from => TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
  :to => @user.phone,
  :body => "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to this message."
)
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Devin Stewart but another error occurred as:        NameError in UsersController#create
uninitialized constant UsersController::Client, on the line  Client.account.sms.messages.create( , mentioned in my controller

Comment: make sure client is not capitalized.

Comment: Thank you for your response but new error occurred as:   Twilio::REST::RequestError in UsersController#create    on the same line i mentioned in my above comment

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that I use 'client.account.messages.create()'  editing answer

Comment: The thing I would check are the values of @user.phone and TWILIO_CONFIG['from'].  Perhaps log those values and see if they are being set correctly.  I used the example from https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby#send-an-sms and all worked well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46609/discussion-between-bindi-bhatt-and-devin-stewart)